# f.select Bad arg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I am trying to use the form_for select helper and I am getting an error trying to make a selection of numbers.  This is my line:

```
<%= f.select(:reminder, options_for_select([ ['0','0'], ['10','10'], ['25','25'] ], {}, {:class => 'form-control'} )) %>
```

and I am getting this error:

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)
```

I have tried formatting my syntax a lot of different ways but I am at an impasse.  Thank you anyone who knows where I am going wrong with my syntax for the select helper.  BTW I was useing this page as a reference:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your closing round bracket for options_for_select is at the wrong place. Try:

```
<%= f.select(:reminder, options_for_select([ ['0','0'], ['10','10'], ['25','25'] ]), {}, {:class => 'form-control'} ) %>
```

[options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select) takes 1 or 2 arguments (2nd argument is optional). Because of the misplaced closing bracket, you are passing 3 arguments to it.

Comment: I am now getting a no method error in which means :reminder is not present in my db correct? I will mark yours as correct if this is the case.

Comment: Probably yes. Will have to see the entire error message to be sure.